# Thin profile wire joins and forks

Tags: connector, wire

I've a project where I'm installing some LED lighting. I am currently using crimp connectors and electrical tape to join two pieces of wire or fork wire, but I find this to be ugly. I would like to know what solder-free alternatives there are to joining two wires or forking wires into 2 or more wires that have a fairly low profile and form good mechanical and electrical connections. The wiring is probably 1-2mm in diameter including insulation.

Comment: Solder + heatshrink looks a lot neater, especially if you can get small-diameter heatshink tubing that matches the color of the wire.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking specifically for solder-free solutions

Comment: Wire joins and forks also known as splices to many. Added comment for keyword capture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wago [Lever-nuts](http://www.wago.us/products/2631.htm) are good for quick reliable connections. I use them all the time when assembling test fixtures or making temporary connections. Wire nuts are also good if the connection is meant to be permanent. Although I haven't used them [these](http://www.wago.us/products/323.htm) seem to be lower profile and maybe closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: The lighting connectors looks good!

Comment: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10144/why-are-wire-nuts-not-used-in-the-uk

This explains a lot ... and also makes me mad. I thought I was stupid because I couldn't find appropriate solutions in the shops...

Answer (score 7):

I prefer non-insulated barrel/butt splices with heatshrink over.  It looks clean and provides a very reliable connection without solder, and at a reasonable cost.  Only inexpensive crimp tools are required.

The raw splices look like this:

[image]

The finished product looks like this (this example uses adhesive-lined heatshrink, though that is unnecessary for indoor applications)

[image]

Don't use the insulated (red/blue/yellow plastic, typically) barrel splices; the insulation often prevents a good crimp and they look awful.

[image]

If you want the insulation built in, use crimp splices that have integral shrink insulation.

[image]